# Is Recurring Payments Profile with Express Checkout available?

Tags: paypal, recurring

I am investigating the recurring payment for paypal. looks express checkout is we we needed. but the document page https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/ is under Express Checkout - NVP/SOAP (Deprecated).

And this page(https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/) said:
Important: This integration method is Deprecated as of January 1, 2017. For new integrations, see the [PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/)

new page doesn't say anything about recurring. 
Is recurring payments still available for paypal express checkout?

Answer (score 2):

They are trying to move away from the Classic APIs, which is why they're labeling them as deprecated now, but they aren't going away any time soon.  There are still way too many people and apps integrated with Classic, and you can still build new apps with those APIs, too.  I still prefer Classic over REST myself.

For the REST API you can take a look at [Billing Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/) and/or [Billing Plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/).

Comment: Andrew, Why you prefer Classic over REST?

Comment: The Classic API is more mature and has features that REST doesn't have yet.  For example, with Express Checkout in Classic you can force the Guest Checkout experience for non-PayPal account holders but you can't do that in REST yet.  Also, parallel payments work well in Classic but not in REST.

Comment: Ok, Is there any security risk for using NVP Classic API? Beacuse i am worried if i am using it, and any bad things happened. Also REST API documentation are not so clear. I want to integrate Recurring Payment using express checkout in Paypal, I implemented using NVP, but find a lot difficulties using REST. Billing Plans and Agreement API are not so clear. Can you please share some working examples for recurring payment using express checkout (checkout.js) in REST.

Answer (score 0):

If you purely created Express Checkout (without having additional API call), you are advise to integrate with Express Checkout v4 which located [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/). But if you wanted to Creates with Recurring Payment, the option is still available. PayPal does not finalize yet the date of deprecation application for Express Checkout.